# Cómo crear un Listener personalizado

Tags: java, android

he estado averiguando sobre como crear un listener personalizado y me topé con esta página: https://medium.com/@kyroschow/android-for-beginners-part-1-creating-custom-listeners-2c1a4b794b7f

Aquí está directamente el código fuente del ejemplo: https://github.com/kyroschow/MediumAndroidTutorials/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/kyros/mediumandroidtutorials/part1/step2/BinaryGame2.java

Básicamente intento implementar un listener personalizado que muestre una notificación una vez hecho una acción:

```
OnSusscefullListener listener;

public Call() {
    
}

public void setOnSusscefullListener(OnSusscefullListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void NotifyAction(int i) {
    listener.onSusscess(i);
}

public interface OnSusscefullListener {
void onSusscess(int a);
}
```

Y cuando lo implemento en mi clase principal queda así:

```
Call call = new Call();

call.setOnSusscefullListener(new Call.OnSusscefullListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSusscess(int t) {

            //Acción a realizar

        }
    });
```

Y de esta forma hago la notificación a través de la clase:

```
Call call = new Call();
        
        call.NotifyAction(v);

//la v representa un int guardado en SharedPreferences
```

Y ahí surge un inconveniente: al intentar notificar no funciona. Muchas gracias, si necesitas más información sobre mi código coméntalo.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de probarlo y funciona correctamente.

Es posible que estés generando una instancia distinta a la que tiene el listener establecido y por eso no te notifica.

Supón que tienes una clase `Persona` (no entraré en detalles sobre la definición por simplicidad).

```
// Se crean 2 instancias de la clase Persona
Persona p1 = new Persona();
Persona p2 = new Persona();
Systen.out.println(p1 == p2) // false
// Cada instancia es independiente de las demás
```

---

Este código funciona:

```
class Call {

    OnSuccessfulListener listener;

    public Call() {
    }

    public void setOnSuccessfulListener(OnSuccessfulListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void NotifyAction(int i) {
        listener.onSuccess(i);
    }

    public interface OnSuccessfulListener {
        void onSuccess(int a);
    }

}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Call call = new Call();
        call.setOnSuccessfulListener(new Call.OnSuccessfulListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int t) {
                System.out.println(t);
            }
        });
        call.NotifyAction(1);
    }

}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##fVGxbsMgEN3zFYx4KFLnKFKrrm0zeKw6UIzTSwlEcHYURf52F2xfjSWnJ4QMz@@9u8dRtvLhWP30vTIyBPYijWG3zYbF2tuyUUqHUDfmFQJqqz0z08d2/OfcfBlQA40XkZjuugXUOqhY0Limxv@1IL1U@A1BEMB2WRt3HN8dQn19VgjOcrDIIJcjunDUAIdiTSsyta@l0utpzIqDaaYWHeWsGNeY75sES/lOFgElUtenCPMSPdjDxyeT/hCK2WJ4G5W2HbP6MoU@erC0J0zci5oYYhUtqCmqp32rvYdKL27zhJfDYh4vVXmN8ifhGhTnOBMay5Eanqr7O3UZMkyyeMLHLMy@/wU).